# Python's unittest fails to pass in parameter "missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'" for Discord bot testing?

Tags: python, unit-testing, async-await, discord, discord.py

I am trying to write a simple test case for one of my Discord.py commands:

https://github.com/NobleUplift/Hierarchies/blob/master/cogs/HierarchyManagement.py#L32

The function definition is quite simple:

```
async def list(self, ctx: discord.ext.commands.Context):
```

And I am trying to write a unit test that replaces `ctx.send` with `print` for now, to validate the output of my Discord command, with the eventual goal to add asserts that validate the output of the command:

```
Hierarchies: 
 • us-army
 • admins
```

Here is my full test case:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import Mock
from unittest.mock import patch

from cogs.HierarchyManagement import HierarchyManagement

class test_Hierarchies(unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    async def test_list(self):
        bot = Mock() # commands.Bot()
        ctx = Mock() # discord.ext.commands.Context()
        ctx.message.content = '^list'
        ctx.message.guild.id = 870166294127837205
        ctx.author.mention = '<@368187588340875284>'
        ctx.author.name = 'NobleUplift'
        ctx.author.discriminator = '1038'
        ctx.send = lambda retval: print(retval)
        print(ctx.message.guild.id)
        hierarchyManagement = HierarchyManagement(bot)
        print(ctx)
        print(hierarchyManagement)
        await hierarchyManagement.list(ctx)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

And this is the error I receive:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\unittest\case.py", line 60, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\unittest\case.py", line 676, in run
    self._callTestMethod(testMethod)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\unittest\async_case.py", line 65, in _callTestMethod
    self._callMaybeAsync(method)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\unittest\async_case.py", line 88, in _callMaybeAsync
    return self._asyncioTestLoop.run_until_complete(fut)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\unittest\async_case.py", line 102, in _asyncioLoopRunner
    ret = await awaitable
  File "Hierarchies\cogs\test_HierarchyManagement.py", line 21, in test_list
    await hierarchyManagement.list(ctx)
  File "Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 374, in __call__
    return await self.callback(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: list() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'
```

Why is it telling me that it requires `ctx` **when I am quite clearly passing in the ctx variable?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is when you define a discord.py command, you'll need to use the `@command()` decorator. The decorator automatically does some conversions and redefines `HierarchyManagement.list` to a `discord.Command` object representing the `list` command. Since decorators are ran without the instance `self`, your `list` method gets stored as a self-less function at `hierarchyManagement.list._callback`.

When you're calling `hierarchyManagement.list()` you're actually calling the `commands.Command.__call__()` dunder method which redirects to `hierarchyManagement.list._callback()`. And we established earlier that the callback doesn't have the `self` reference.

This is why, you'll need to do:

```py
await hierarchyManagement.list(hierarchyManagement, ctx)
```

The reason why it works "magically" when discord.py runs it is because during command argument parsing, they inject the `self` into the function callback at runtime. Since calling `hierarchyManagement.list` direct skips all the parsing, the `self` wasn't injected in your case.

As an aside, `ctx.send` is a coroutine, but when you defined it in mock `ctx.send = lambda retval: print(retval)` its a regular function, this will raise an error later on.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was driving me CRAZY. You know what's funny? I tried to do both `hierarchyManagement.list(ctx=ctx)` and `hierarchyManagement.list(hierarchyManagement=hierarchyManagement, ctx=ctx)` but I didn't listen to the errors telling me to use positional arguments instead of keyword arguments and put 2+2 together.

Comment: Do you know how  to mock `ctx.send` as a coroutine so that it prints to console?

Comment: @NobleUplift just instead of using lambda, use `async def send(*args, **kwargs): print(args, kwargs)` and set `ctx.send = send`

Comment: I got it working over the weekend and started writing my test cases. Thanks for the help! So glad to finally start using test-driven development with this bot.